# Show Edit item button for a rendering in experience editor

Tags: experience-editor

How do I enable or show the "Edit Item" button for a rendering?

I see this when looking at example Habitat Project (8.x version), but I don't see on my Sitecore 9 implementation.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a custom button made and enabled for Habitat as a showcase. You can find it under `FieldEditor` Foundation module -> https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/src/Foundation/FieldEditor/serialization/WebEdit.FieldEditorAll/Edit%20Item.yml

Here is link for Sitecore 9 branch -> https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/feature/v9/src/Foundation/FieldEditor/serialization/WebEdit.FieldEditorAll/Edit%20Item.yml

Comment: That seems not to work any more in Sitecore 9.3

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps

1. Login into Sitecore Content Editor.
2. Select the database as "Core"
3. Go to the item '/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Default Rendering Buttons/Options'
4. Assign Security Rights on the "Options" as **Read** and **Write**

Comment: I gave that a go, but doesn't seem to have worked.. Did I need to assign the rights to a specific role? I'm logged in as the administrator currently.

Comment: yes it should be with the role you are trying to edit. In this case Sitecore/Admin

Comment: Comparing items in the Default Rendering Buttons list between my site, and habitat, I can see habitat has an extra option for "Edit Item".. I'll see if I can add same one in my application

Comment: Seems this is a custom button in Habitat, and not an out of the box option..